# Whats the difference between JSONObject[] and JSONObject?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am constructing an AsyncTask in android and I have passed a `JSONObect` to the `doInBackground()` method but when I try to run `getString` on it, it complains that `getString` can't be run on a `JSONObject[]` object. This is a problem, anyone know how to get `JSONObject[]` to `JSONObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObject[]` would indicate and array of `JSONObject`.  If you know there is only a single item in the array you can try calling it like myJsonObject[0]

Comment: Any idea why passing a `JSONObject` through an AsyncTask converts it to an array?

Comment: @sightofnick Read about variable arguments ("varargs") in Java.